# Fancybox doesn't work after a success of an ajax call

Tags: c#, fancybox

Why is not working fancybox after check validation in c#?

fancybox is call after `use PageMethods.ValidacionIsAdmin(onSuccessValidacionIsAdmin);` if it is valid the return of database executed in:

```
[WebMethod]
public static DeleteAccountResult ValidacionIsAdmin()
{
   DeleteAccountResult res = new DeleteAccountResult();

   ... // Query to database with ok results

   res.ok = true;

   return res;
}
```

The ajax call in client to validate it is:

```
jQuery(".delete a").click(function () {

            function onSuccessValidacionIsAdmin(data) {
                if (data.ok == true) {
                    jQuery("#<%= divError.ClientID %>").hide();

                    jQuery(".delete a").fancybox({
                        content: jQuery('#eliminar-cuenta').html(),
                        modal: false,
                        showCloseButton: false,
                        onComplete: function () {
                            jQuery("input[type=checkbox]").uniform()

                            jQuery('#privacidad').fancybox({
                                enableEscapeButton: false,
                                hideOnOverlayClick: false,
                                showCloseButton: true,
                                onComplete: function () {
                                    jQuery('#fancybox-close').off().on('click', function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        jQuery(".delete a").click();
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    jQuery("#<%= divError.ClientID %>").show();
                    jQuery("#lblError")[0].innerHTML = data.strError;
                }
            }

            PageMethods.ValidacionIsAdmin(onSuccessValidacionIsAdmin);
        });
```

The Behaviour is look like after to push the link which open fancybox don't open it, looks like it "refresh" the web and I push the same link and then it is working...

I readed fancy doesn't work after an ajax call (in my case the c# validation)

My question is: why it happens?

Comment: yes, what should i see in fiddle?

Comment: you can make demo there and put link here so other user can play with it http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: how  can i simulate ajax request? in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of investigation, I got the solution. It is curious, in all propierties ineas to write content: ... I replaced as: 'content': ...

I added the property 'type':'html'

After do that the fancybox was working.

```
 jQuery(".delete a").fancybox({
    'content': jQuery('#eliminar-cuenta').html(),
     'type': 'html',
    'modal': false,
    'showCloseButton': false,
    'onComplete': function () {
        jQuery("input[type=checkbox]").uniform()

        jQuery('#privacidad').fancybox({
            enableEscapeButton: false,
            hideOnOverlayClick: false,
            showCloseButton: true,
            onComplete: function () {
                jQuery('#fancybox-close').off().on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    jQuery(".delete a").click();
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess it was more the `type:'html'` option that did the trick

Comment: It was curious but when I did that change everything is working, except when you push close in the corner the dialog apperas again and it is a loop. with showCloseButton to false I avoid user click ther and i write at end of dialog a normal button to close. But now it is working